# as if + past simple/ as if + past perfect

Tags: meaning

1 We decided to pretend as if nothing had happened yesterday.

2 We decided to pretend as if nothing happened yesterday.

What's the difference?

This is useless [Sentence structure, As if - "As if + past" vs "As if past perfect"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51795/sentence-structure-as-if-as-if-past-vs-as-if-past-perfect)

Comment: We don't pretend 'as if' xxx happened; we **pretend that** xxx happened**. We might **act as if** xxx happened.

Answer (score 1):

I must agree with the comment by Michael Harvey, "*pretend as if*" is not natural English.

> - (3) We decided to act as if nothing happened yesterday

> - (4) We decided to act as if nothing had happened yesterday

Sentences (3) and (4) are both grammatically valid and have much the same meaning. (4) Perhaps emphasizes the past nature of the events more